# Error when setting MemoryStream as the source of a BitMapImage

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, memorystream, bitmapimage

For Windows Phone 8 development, everything I've read is saying that you have to set a stream as the source of a bitmapimage in order to convert a byte[] array to a bitmapimage. When I implement this though, I receive an error at:

```
 bitmapImage.SetSource(stream);
```

Error:

```
 An exception of type 'System.Exception' occurred in System.Windows.ni.dll 
 but was not handled in user code

 Additional information: The component cannot be found. (Exception from 
 HRESULT: 0x88982F50)
```

Code Snippet:

```
 byte[] bytes = value as byte[];
 MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
 BitmapImage bitmapImage = new BitmapImage();
 bitmapImage.SetSource(stream);
```

Comment: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/6590eb57-98cf-4b9f-b2d8-6e7aae9c00a2/cant-convert-byte-to-bitmapimage-component-cannot-be-found-error?forum=winappswithcsharp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The array you have stored in `bytes` is not a valid image. You need to go further back to wherever `value` is getting populated and find out why it is not being populated with the byte array for a image.

Comment: My app takes a picture, sends it to a wcf service, and that sends it to a sql server database, which is where I access it later on from a different page in the app. You wouldn't happen to know if this line of code is causing it would you?: byte[] theBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(upload);    It's how I turn the image into bytes on my wcf service in order to add it to the sql server database.

Comment: Yes that is the source of your problem, you can not send arbitrary data through `Encoding.` methods. If you need to convert it to a string you can use [`Convert.ToBase64String`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dhx0d524(v=vs.110).aspx) and [`Convert.FromBase64String`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.frombase64string(v=vs.110).aspx). However the better thing to do is have your sql table use a `varbinary` instead of a `varchar` then you never need to convert it to a string at all.

Comment: You are the man! I took your advice and turned the HttpPostedFile into a byte[] array, and the problem is finally solved.

Answer (score 1):

Often weird errors like this are caused by a failure to set the stream to the starting position. Also, it's good practice to wrap disposable objects in a using statement.

Does this solve the problem?

```
 var bytes = value as byte[]; 
 using(var stream = new MemoryStream(bytes, 0, bytes.Length))
 {
    //set this to the beginning of the stream
    stream.Position = 0;
    var bitmapImage = new BitmapImage();
    bitmapImage.SetSource(stream);
 }
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it's giving the same error at the same spot.